# Sharing owin cookie authentication between mvc 5 and web api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have an mvc 5 app that uses a web api 2, api.

MVC app uses owin cookie authentication to authenticate the user and it works fine. The requirement is that if the user is signed into the MVC app, he should also be able to access the secured methods in the API.

When there was asp.net forms auth, I used the same machine key in both the API and MVC to successfully authenticate users from the APP in the api. But cannot get it to work with the owin cookie authentication.

Here are the auth sections from both the API and MVC app.

API

```
 HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,                
        });
```

MVC APP

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login")
        });
```

web.configs in both the projects have the same machine keys entered. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following line was the problem for me.  It was in the Register method in my WebpiConfig.cs file.

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```